# How to add array elements in java?

Tags: java, arrays

my issue is:

The array limit is 25.  How do i add it?  I'm not supposed to use `ArrayList` integer.parseInt, append and Stringbuilder. It also has fileReading part.

File content is formatted as below:

```
28 6 
9 5 
2000 2001 
0
1 23 4
```

Below is the expected output:

```
28 + 6 = 34 
9 + 5 = 14 
2000 + 2001 = 4001 
0 = 0 
1 + 23 + 4 = 28
```

I need help adding the elements. Here's my code, so far.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Sum {
  public static final int arbitraryNum = 25; // class constant for setting constant values 

  // main method
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    fileProcessing(); // call the file reading method
  }

  //reads from a given file and then passes it to the next method. 
  public static void fileProcessing() throws FileNotFoundException{
    File reading = new File("sum.txt"); // file call
    Scanner lineByLine = new Scanner(reading); // reads lines by line to count the total lines
    Scanner wordByWord = new Scanner(reading);
    Scanner console = new Scanner(reading); // total number of tokens 
    Scanner tokensInLine = new Scanner(reading); //number
    int totalLines = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int tokenCount = 0;
    String lines = "";
    String words = "";
    String tokens ="";
    String[] token;
    String[] lineStore = null;

    while(lineByLine.hasNextLine()){
      totalLines++;
      lines = lineByLine.nextLine();
    }

    lineStore = new String[totalLines];
    while(tokensInLine.hasNextLine()){
      tokens = tokensInLine.nextLine();
      totalLines++;
      lineStore[b++] = tokens;
    }

    while(console.hasNext()){
      tokens = console.next();
      tokenCount++;
    }
    token = new String[tokenCount];
    while(wordByWord.hasNext()){
      words = wordByWord.next();
      token[a++] = words;
    }
    leadingZeros(token, lineStore);
    System.out.println("Total lines = " + totalLines);
    System.out.println("Token count = " + tokenCount);
  }
  // adds leading zeros.
  public static String leadingZeros(String[] tokens, String[] Line){
    String[] number = tokens;
    String s = ""; 
    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
      s= "0000000000000000000000000"+number[i]; 
      String[] hello = {s.substring(s.length()-25)} ;
      StringToIntConversion(tokens, (s.substring(s.length()-25)), Line);
      //   System.out.println(s.substring(s.length()-25));
    }
    return s;
  }

  //converts the string to integer meaning, string ====> char ====> int
  public static int[] StringToIntConversion(String[] tokens, String num, String[] line) {
    int[] a = new int[arbitraryNum];
    int sum = 0;
    for(int v = 0; v < arbitraryNum; v++){
      a[v] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(v)) ;
      sum += a[v];
      //System.out.print(sum);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)); // to show array structure
    //  
    //int[][] add = new int[line.length][tokens.length];
    //for(int r = 0; r < add.length; r++){
    //  for(int p = 0; p < add[0].length; p++){
    //    for(int v = 0; v < arbitraryNum; v++){
    //      add[r][p] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(v));
    //      System.out.print(add[r][p] + sum);
    //    }
    //    System.out.println();
    //  }
    //}
    //              

    addition(a, tokens, line);
    return a;
  }

  // adds data from the previous method 
  public static void addition(int[] kilo, String[] token, String[] lineStore){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int a = 0; a < arbitraryNum; a++){
      //how should i add
      enter code here
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: You declare a new array of the required size, copy the contents from the old one and assign the new array to the old variable...

Comment: @MadProgrammer --- The output of after StringToIntConversion() looks like ex: 00000000...6  (24 zeros before 6). -- 0,0,0,...,6. But, thank you for the help.

Comment: I thought its sum of a number and its next number, but its little confusing. Can you explain `0 = 0 1 + 23 + 4 = 28` part?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PavanKumar! The sum part should be like  0 = 0, meaning if the line has only one token in the file, then it should print the token = token. 1 + 23 + 4 = 28 , is in another line of the same file. I couldn't format it. Sorry about it. Also the file can contain any integer, 1 + 23 + 4 is just an example.

Comment: @TeslaCarsForLife I have made edits in the question and posted an answer based on that. Please check and share your inputs. If the solution works, please do accept the answer so that others are informed that this is resolved.

Comment: Thank you a lot @PavanKumar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the latest comments, below would work for you - Please note that I haven't taken care of error check etc.

```
   public static void fileProcessing() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String reading = "28 6\n9 5\n2000 2001\n0\n1 23 4";
        Scanner lineByLine = new Scanner(reading); // reads lines by line to
                                                    // count the total lines
        String lines = "";

        while (lineByLine.hasNextLine()) {
            lines = lineByLine.nextLine();
            String[] nums = lines.split(" ");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            BigInteger sum = new BigInteger("0");
            for(String num : nums){
                sb.append("+").append(num);
                sum = sum.add(new BigInteger(num));
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString().substring(1)+"="+sum);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 28+6=34
9+5=14
2000+2001=4001
0=0
1+23+4=28

Comment: The file might contain any number - numbers large as 25 digits. what should i do in such cases.

Comment: Integer has a limited range with max value of 2147483647. Use BigInteger instead. Updated teh code accordingly.